# React Native Polygon Location

Tags: api, location, react-native-maps

I am developing a mobile application where the parent can track their child's location instantly. I can take the child's instant position.The parent will be notified when he leaves the black area. About 100 locations arrived in this black area But I don't know how to get out of a designated area. Do I need to take all their positions and determine the radius? And this application is my graduation project[image]

Comment: Why the black area? Is it always this area? if not, how the restricted area is determine?

Comment: How do I know if the child's position is within the drawn black area? This region will be determined by the parent.(this black zone can always change, the parent pulls himself)

Comment: How does the parent determines it? He draws it? if so then how?

Comment: The system consists of two sides, the child side and the parent side. The parent side draws this area. I drew this drawing using react native polygon. My problem is not drawing. The location parameters in this area I draw are too many. There are 100 latitude longtitude parameters. My aim is that the parent will draw this area. I need to send an SMS when it comes out of this field. It is very difficult for me to do this with so many parameters. How can I do if I do something like Radius? (My English is so bad I hope you understand)

Comment: See my answer. After asking all these questions I hope I finally understood what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your English is good. Not worst than mine ;)

What you are looking for is a function that returns a boolean value that tells you if a specific position is out of the polygon.

This function can be found in the [react-native-geo-fencing](https://github.com/surialabs/react-native-geo-fencing) package.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
import GeoFencing from 'react-native-geo-fencing';


...
  const polygon = [
    { lat: 3.1336599385978805, lng: 101.31866455078125 },
    { lat: 3.3091633559540123, lng: 101.66198730468757 },
    { lat: 3.091150714460597,  lng: 101.92977905273438 },
    { lat: 2.7222113428196213, lng: 101.74850463867188 },
    { lat: 2.7153526167685347, lng: 101.47933959960938 },
    { lat: 3.1336599385978805, lng: 101.31866455078125 } // last point has to be same as first point
  ];

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      let point = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      GeoFencing.containsLocation(point, polygon)
        .then(() => console.log('point is within polygon'))
        .catch(() => console.log('point is NOT within polygon'))
    },
    (error) => alert(error.message),
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );
...
```

This example was taken from the **react-native-geo-fencing documentation**.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark this answer as useful so others with the same problem will know the answer is valid.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5nvMQe-fpc